# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, cookie

Почему ошибка?

```
setcookie("auto", "yes", time()+9999999);
setcookie("email", "email123", time()+9999999);
setcookie("password", "password123", time()+9999999);
setcookie("id", "id123", time()+9999999);

setcookie ("TestCookie","TestCookie");
```

на этот код выдают ошибки

> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\qb1.cam\www\Test.php:4) in Z:\home\qb1.cam\www\Test.php on line 10`
>
> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\qb1.cam\www\Test.php:4) in Z:\home\qb1.cam\www\Test.php on line 11`
>
> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\qb1.cam\www\Test.php:4) in Z:\home\qb1.cam\www\Test.php on line 12`
>
> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\qb1.cam\www\Test.php:4) in Z:\home\qb1.cam\www\Test.php on line 13`
>
> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\qb1.cam\www\Test.php:4) in Z:\home\qb1.cam\www\Test.php on line 16`

Почему ?

Comment: Потому что заголовки не могут быть выставлены после вывода тела страницы, если выключена буферизация ob_*  
Сначала делаете header и cookie, потом тело страницы. Или используете буферизацию.

Comment: А можно пример или что .. Ато я ничего не понял :(

Comment: Он говорит, что эти строки с setcookie должны стоять в начале, перед выводом контента.

Comment: Вообще лучше всегда юзать буферизацию, если это не шаблон.
p.s. вместо echo используйте строковую переменную и выводите ее echoм в конце логики всей, и после установки заголовков.

Comment: Аесли к этому файлу обращается при помощи асинхронного соединение с дргой строници это не страшно ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед установкой заголовка header, куки или сессии не надо ничего выводить. Поищи в своём коде, есть какой либо выводи перед setcookie. И бывает такое что php файл закрывают <? ... ?> и после него перенос строки стоит, это тоже считается как вывод, так что лучше php файл открывать <?php и не закрывать вообще, во избежания случайного вывода.

Comment: А еще если файл в utf с BOM, то BOM php будет считать данными для вывода в браузер.